# Find all Wikidata items whose image (P18) URL contains a certain word

Tags: images, wikidata, sparql

I am trying to find all Wikidata items whose P18 property is an URL that has the word "Montage" anywhere in its filename.

Example:

[image]

I managed to [find items by their complete P18 filename](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11906/find-all-wikidata-items-that-use-a-particular-p18-picture):

```
SELECT ?item
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P18 <http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Montage%20Columbus%201.jpg>.
}
```

But now I would like to add wildcards to that. My attempts with `*` and [contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628006/sparql-query-for-partial-match-of-statement-contains)/regex all failed.

How to achieve that?

Comment: https://w.wiki/7gq 416 results

Comment: @StanislavKralin: Wonderful, it works, thanks! And the `hint:Query` trick is gold. Feel free to post an answer containing the query, so that I can accept it. If not I will post and accept myself ^_^

Comment: please feel free to post an answer yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but not an answer:

https://query.wikidata.org/#%23Distribution%20of%20names%20of%20human%20settlements%20ending%20in%20%22-ow%22%20or%20%22-itz%22%20in%20Germany%0A%23added%20before%202016-10%0A%20%23defaultView%3AMap%0ASELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fcoord%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%09%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ486972%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP17%20wd%3AQ183%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FitemLabel%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fcoord%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FitemLabel%29%20%3D%20%22de%22%29%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20FILTER%20regex%20%28%3FitemLabel%2C%20%22%28ow%7Citz%29%24%22%29.%0A%7D

is an example of how to do this using FILTER and regex.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work: https://w.wiki/7eY (`0 results in 42783 ms`) Probably because my question is about an URL, and your comment is about a simple string.

Comment: `regex(str(?url), "Montage")` or `hint:Query hint:regexMatchNonString true` .

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use `str` inside the `contains`.

This query gives the expected result:

```
select ?item ?img
{
  hint:Query hint:maxParallel 400 .
  hint:Query hint:chunkSize  8000 .
  ?item wdt:P18 ?img . 
  filter contains(str(?img), "Montage")
}
```

[Try it](https://w.wiki/7gq)

Another way to achieve this is to set `hint:Query hint:regexMatchNonString true` and then use a normal regex.

(Huge thanks to Stanislav Kralin who found all this)